# bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Suddenly I started to get error when I try to open my dropdown menu :

```
 bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)
        at bootstrap.min.js:6
        at bootstrap.min.js:6
        at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

I am using standard bootstrap file

> `<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">`

Anything changed in bootstrap I have to take care off?

Order I am loading files is following

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>




<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 navbar doesn't work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634415/bootstrap-3-navbar-doesnt-work-anymore)

Answer (score 112):

In the introduction of Bootstrap it states which imports you need to add. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start

You have to add some scripts in order to get bootstrap fully working. It's important that you include them in this exact order. Popper.js is one of them:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: yes you are correct, thanks. However it is something new. Since it always worked without those additional inclusions.

Comment: also it happens due to bootstrap updates if I switch to CDN it also works
https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: It use to be tether.js that was needed.

Comment: This exact order fixed it for me in Angular 5 angular-cli.json.

Comment: Also important to have the scripts in that order **1.Jquery 2.Popper 3.Bootstrap**

Comment: here is how to install popper using npm : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039812/how-to-install-popper-js-with-bootstrap-4

Comment: I had the links in that exact order (jquery js, popper js, bootstrap js) and it still gave the same error for me.

Answer (score 110):

Instead of:

```
js/bootstrap.min.js
```

use:

```
js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
```

Comment: This works, without adding any scripts in index.html and no further node modules needed in SPW applications.

Comment: This is the fastest, simplest fix and if you're getting the popper error, using the bundle which includes popper, is the way to go. note: you still need to include jQuery before bootstrap.bundle.min.js as jQuery is not part of the bundle.

Comment: Yeah it really worked fine for me I just changed 
`{"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"}`
to
`{"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"} `

and it worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: thanks I was having this problem after migrate bootstrap 3 to 4! this solved!

Answer (score 38):

Bootstrap 4 is not yet a mature tool yet. The part of requiring another plugin to work is even more complicated especially for developers who have been using Bootstrap for a while. I have seen many ways to eliminate the error but not all work for everyone. I think the best and cleanest way to work with Bootstrap 4. Among the Bootstrap installation files, There is one with the name ***"bootstrap.bundle.js"***
that already comes with the Popper included.

Comment: Go to  : https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap  find  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js  Which worked for me

Comment: Worked for me . Thank you.

Comment: You are the real hero

Comment: TOTAL HERO. This is the answer.

Comment: It works, and we should include it before the bootstrap js, all here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 27):

include popper.js before bootstrap.min.js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.0.4/popper.js"></script>
```

use this link to get popper

Comment: also had to put above jquery/dist/jquery.min.js is what worked for me   so i have Popper -then- jquery - then bootstrap

Comment: easiest and fastest fix.

Answer (score 13):

In order for Bootstrap Beta to function properly, you must place the scripts in the following order.

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694811/how-to-use-popper-js-with-bootstrap-4-beta?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) you must use the script in the UMD subdirectory, in my case

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/projectbundle").Include(
            "~/Scripts/umd/popper.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/respond.js",
            "~/Scripts/summernote-bs4.js"));
```

Specifically this: "~/Scripts/umd/popper.js",

Comment: This is what did it for me. I compared mine to the working CDN I copied from an above answer and this was the difference.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install popperjs along with bootstrap to get rid of this error.Note that if you are using "bootstrap": "^4.4.1", and @popperjs/core v2.x combinations,bootstrap may not support popperjs version. So downgrade your version.

Option 1:
`npm install popper.js@^1.12.9 --save`

and Add following script between jquery and bootstrap scripts.

`"node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"`,

Option 2:
Add following script tag to index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script
```

Comment: I did Option 2. Works perfect

Comment: Thanks, good catch! Bootstrap 4 works only with Popper 1.x

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with an MVC project and here is how I fixed it.

1. Open *BundleConfig.cs*
2. Find :

   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

   Change to:

   ```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"));
   ```

This will set the bundle file to load. It is already in the correct order. You just have to make sure that you are rendering this bundle in your view.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am using Visual Studio and Nuget packages its failing because have duplicated libraries one in the same folder as jQuery and another in the folder umd. By removing the popper javascript files from the same level as jQuery and refere to the popper.js inside the umd folder fixed my issue and I can see the tooltips correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue, then I put my dropdown in nav tag.
Worked for me that way.

Answer (score 0):

On moving a .html template to a wordpress one, I found this "popper required" popping up regularly :)

Two reasons it happened for me: and the console error can be deceptive:

1. The error in the console can **send you down the wrong path**. It MIGHT not be the real issue. First reason for me was the **order** in which you have set your .js files to load. In html easy, put them in the same order as the theme template. In Wordpress, you need to enqueue them in the right order, but also set a priority if they don't appear in the right order,
2. Second thing is are the .js files in the **header or the footer**. Moving them to the footer can solve the issue - it did for me, after a day of trying to debug the issue. Usually doesn't matter, but for a complex page with lots of js libraries, it might!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and just wanted to share my solution.
In turned out that the minified version of popper had the code in the same line as the comment and so the entire code was commented out.
I just pressed enter after the actual comment so the code was on a new line and then it worked fine.