# Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I used a layout(Gentelella) for my project everything was fine and then in the middle of production, when I tried to run my project and some of the layout is not working (the dropdown).

So I have encountered this kind of error, I kind to manage the error by adding this [popper.js file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.0.4/popper.js) as said in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661863/bootstrap-min-js6-uncaught-error-bootstrap-dropdown-require-popper-js) and writing it before my scripts but the problem is it destroyed my layout.

How can I fix this?

And I noticed from searching some answer for this problem, this error occur just few days ago from others. Never saw a topic about this problem posted older than a week(base on the date this question is posted).

Comment: How are you including your js files? Do you get console errors? Where's the broken layout?? do you have a link you can share?  some code of the dropdown as well???

Comment: @Juan here is the layout [link](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella). Yes Im having console errors (the title). It's not only the dropdown that has a problem, but i think its the js(not so sure)

Comment: I opened this [link](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html) but I don't get any errors. Can you please update your question an provide all the information: Which dropdown in your website, direct link to where the error is. Or if we have to clone the github project and run it, maybe steps to reproduce, some screenshots would help.

Comment: use proper CDN link to bootstrap css and js file instead of dist link of bootstrap. because the dist link redirects you to latest version of bootstrap it may cause errors.                                                                        reference : https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7