# How to install popper.js with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popper.js

From what I've read so far, popper.js is a big pain with Bootstrap 4. I can't get it to work. I keep getting this error:

> Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)

I've tried the CDN and NPM install. Same result. At the bottom of my HTML file, I have this for the NPM install:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Then tried this for the CDN:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/popper.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript related errors when you inspect your code?  See also: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: @RobertC: The CDN from that link seems to fix this issue. I guess at least for bs4, you need Popper 1.12.3 and not 1.12.6 (NPM version).

Comment: Just go to the [Bootstrap home page](https://getbootstrap.com/) and copy/paste the CDN entries for script and CSS.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/popper.js does not look like a right src for popper, it does not specify the file

with bootstrap 4 I am using this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and it is working perfectly fine, give it a try

Comment: it works. can you explain what is the difference between them?

Comment: This: 

<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/popper.js"></script> 

should refer to a ".js" file. What he has takes you to a web page with different versions of popper.js instead. Copy the link and paste it in your browser and you'll see the page. Hope that helps

Answer (score 83):

Bootstrap 4 has two dependencies: jQuery 1.9.1 and popper.js 1.12.3. When you install Bootstrap 4, you need to install these two dependencies.

- Install popper.js: `npm install popper.js@^1.12.3 --save`
- Install jQuery: `npm install jquery@1.9.1 --save`
- Install Bootstrap: `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 --save`

For Bootstrap 4.1

- `npm install popper.js@^1.14.3 --save`
- `npm install jquery@3.3.1 --save`
- `npm install bootstrap@4.1.1 --save`

Comment: I could of swore I can across a post that allows you to do a one-line action with all three packages....I can't find it darn!

Comment: I have installed popper with npm, but it's still referenced from the bootstrap folder: ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'popper.js' in 'D:\Code\MyApp\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js'
 @ ./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 7:101-121
 @ ./ClientApp/boot.ts
 @ multi event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.ts

Comment: I changed version only for jQureey and  Popper and working well with Bootstrap 4

`npm install popper.js@^1.12.9 --save  `
 `npm install jquery@3.2.1 --save   `
 `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0 --save   `

Comment: There is another packet called popper and I always get confused between them.

Comment: Add the script files in angular.json file under scripts array as mentioned below. Please note that order of the script files is important and you need to use the umd version of popper js. : =============== >>>>>

"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",              
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]

Answer (score 25):

Try doing this:

```
npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js --save
```

See this page for more information: [how-to-include-bootstrap-in-your-project-with-webpack](https://stevenwestmoreland.com/2018/01/how-to-include-bootstrap-in-your-project-with-webpack.html)

Comment: Work for me, but adding specific version.

Answer (score 8):

Two different ways I got this working.

**Option 1:** 
Add these 3 `<script>` tags to your `.html` file, just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Option 2** 
(Option 2 works with Angular, not sure about other frameworks)

*Step 1:* Install the 3 libraries using NPM:

`npm install bootstrap --save`

`npm install popper.js --save`

`npm install jquery --save`

*Step 2:* Update the `script:` array(s) in your `angular.json` file like this:

```
"scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js", "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
```

(thanks to @rakeshk-khanapure above in the comments)

Comment: I tried this because I like the angular.json solution. This does not work for me. Dropdown button does not work :/ Using Angular 12.2.11

Answer (score 7):

I had problems installing it Bootstrap as well, so I did:

**Install popper.js:** `npm install popper.js@^1.12.3 --save`

**Install jQuery:** `npm install jquery@1.9.1 --save`

Then I had a  *high severity vulnerability* message when installing jquery@1.9.1 and got this message:

> run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

So I did `npm audit fix`, and after another `npm audit fix --force` it successfully installed!

Answer (score 5):

`npm install bootstrap jquery --save`

You don't have to install popper.js with npm as it comes with npm Bootstrap in `bootstrap.bundle.js`.

> Bundled JS files (bootstrap.bundle.js and minified bootstrap.bundle.min.js) include Popper, but not jQuery.

Source to Verify: [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap#whats-included)

Now you only have to do this in your HTML file:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Pawel** and **Jobayer** has already mentioned about how to install popper.js through npm.

If you are using front-end package manager like bower. use the following command

```
bower install popper.js --save
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simple you can [Visit this](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js), And save the file as popper.min.js

then import it.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './index.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/popper.min.js';
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

Comment: I think this is simple, Though i am not using it this way :)

Comment: As you wish bro. But it's simple

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work-around:

1. Create a `js` directory in the same directory as your index.html
2. Download popper.min.js from the following site into said `js` directory
   https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js#installation

e.g.:
https://unpkg.com/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js

2. Change your the src of your script include to look like this:

   src="js/popper.min.js"

Note that you've removed Popper from `npm` version control, so you'll have to manually download updates.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem while learning Node.js 
Here is my solution for it
to install jquery

```
npm install jquery@1.9.1 --save
npm install popper.js@^1.12.9 --save
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of remotely putting popper js from CDN
you can directly install it in your angular project.

> Try this.

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

This query installs an updated version of popper.js
Don't mention any version there, it will work for you.