# How to fix this error : " Module not found :can't resolve popper.js "

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-popper

After import the Bootstrap and Jquery this error is showning when compiling.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './index.css';

global.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

Comment: this will happen when i add global.jQuery in after import './index.css';                           Line 7:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first

Comment: If this is a browser env, do `import $ from 'jquery'; import 'bootstrap'; window.jQuery = $;`

Comment: but still have popper.js error mate. :(

Comment: Where and how are you importing that popper.js?

Comment: i didn't add. i try to install bootstrap and jquery only.

Comment: I guess it's just a warning as it's the dependency of Bootstrap. Are you using any pop up components in your project?

Comment: If it's used you could just resolve it by doing ```npm -i popper.js```

Comment: no i am not using pop up components. How to import popper.js when it install?

Comment: It is something bootstrap uses for showing tooltips. The resolution to your problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039812/how-to-install-popper-js-with-bootstrap-4

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Popper.js is a dependency of Bootstrap 4 which is used for showing popups. It is a peer dependency of bootstrap meaning it is something that bootstrap requires but doesn't include with itself when installed.
So to install popper.js run

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

It is setup as a peer dependency because some people just use the css of Bootstrap without the javascript.
jQuery and popper.js are the peer dependencies which needs to be installed separately. If you require the javascript of Bootstrap you need to install jQuery and popper.js alongside Bootstrap 4.

---

**Bootstrap 5** requires "Popper.js **Core**", not Popper.js. You should run this instead:

```
npm install @popperjs/core --save
```

(thanks @Kyouma for adding this in the comments)

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks. Although, wouldn't it be preferable to use `--save-dev`?

Comment: @JCarlos It's not technically a dev dependency if it is required for your application to run. So --save makes more sense here.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, although I think it is not a nice example by bootstrap. better would be to split their package then to have js and css seperate, this would be much cleaner

Comment: Just a note - popper.js is now a legacy version. bootstrap 5.x will support `npm i @popperjs/core` instead. The above code (completely correct) is current through v4.x.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Popper.js Core instead of Popper.js, it's solved

Comment: Interesting that it's only my Windows machine that shows this compile error! No worries on my Mac: Bootstrap 5 and no popper.

Answer (score 24):

For **bootstrap 5** you are to

npm users:
`npm install @popperjs/core --save`

for yarn users:
`yarn add @popperjs/core`

then import bootstrap like so:

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';
```

Comment: Worked for me with Rails 7 esbuild, Stimulus and yarn. No React. How do people figure out how to fix these problems? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

It's simple you can [Visit this](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js), And save the file as popper.min.js

then import it.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './index.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/popper.min.js';
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

Comment: Works great and without change webpack.

Answer (score 5):

Like tomi0505 have written, you need to import bootstrap and other things like this:

```
import 'jquery';
import '@popperjs/core'; // Edit here
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';
```

After that it will work fine, I hope.

Answer (score 5):

I also ran into the same issue and was installing popper using the following command :-

```
npm install vue-popperjs --save
```

But, Then I realise I was using bootstrap 5, Which no longer supports this command.
So The command used with bootstrap 5 for "Popperjs Core",

```
npm install @popperjs/core --save
```

Answer (score 3):

You can direct import like

```
import bootstrapBundle from './../path to node modules/../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';
```

no need to install popper

Answer (score 2):

Add the popper.js as dependency in your package.json file like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "popper.js": "1.16.1",
    ...,
  }
}
```

and also add popper.js as required import before adding required bootstrap, as following:

```
require('popper.js');
require('bootstrap');
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have installed:
`npm install jquery popper.js`

instead:
`global.jQuery = require('jquery');`
`require('bootstrap');`

add:

`import $ from 'jquery';`
`import Popper from 'popper.js';`
`import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';`

[look this](https://officialrajdeepsingh.medium.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-in-react-js-adf50165c7a1)

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap 5** requires "Popper.js Core", You Can run this instead:

```
npm install @popperjs/core --save
```

Answer (score 1):

```
npm i bootstrap@4.6.2
```

this code in the best solution. because bootstrap use popper in this version separately.