# cant add bootstrap-carousel for my React App

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap, popper.js, react-popper

I copied  carousel code in bootstap react page.  it gave this error : **./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@popperjs/core' in .....**

.However, I did install popper.js by typing **npm install popper.js** Also I tried this: **npm install popper.js --save**. And I imported at beginning of the page like so :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Carousel } from 'bootstrap';
import Popper from 'popper.js';
```

What did I wrong please help me. Also Should import same thing in my index.js file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix this error : " Module not found :can't resolve popper.js "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459917/how-to-fix-this-error-module-not-found-cant-resolve-popper-js)

Comment: @NaveenSetty yes. in return I got this error: TypeError: Class constructor Carousel cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: make sure that you are using the react version of bootstrap: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/