# How can I use bootstrap 5 Javascript in my Next JS app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, next.js, bootstrap-5

This is my first experience with Next JS and I am trying to bootstrap the Next JS app, which has been going on well until now that I have to use bootstrap's Javascript for a carousel.

So first, I added the bootstrap js to the script of the next js page (`pages/gallery/[id].js`) manually like this:

```
import Script from "next/script";
import Layout from "../../layouts/interface";
import SlidingComponent from "../../components/slide";

export default function GalleryPage() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const {id} = router.query;

  return (
    <Layout>
    <SlidingComponent />

   <Script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

This works initially but as soon as the second slide image comes in, next js throws the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

Call Stack
st._setActiveIndicatorElement
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js (6:13913)
st._slide
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js (6:15057)
st.next
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js (6:10814)
st.nextWhenVisible
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js (6:10883
```

I found another way to correct the error online. It says I should import the bootstrap js in my `pages/_app.js` like this:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import '../styles/globals.css'
import {useEffect} from "react";

//this is what the solution says:
useEffect(() => {
    import("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap");
}, []);

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

But this too gives me the following error:

```
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
wait  - compiling...
error - ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js:7:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '@popperjs/core'

Import trace for requested module:
./pages/_app.js
```

Now I don't even know what to do, can anybody please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix this error : " Module not found :can't resolve popper.js "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459917/how-to-fix-this-error-module-not-found-cant-resolve-popper-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Approach 2, for the popperjs error follow these steps

`npm i @popperjs/core`

- see here [How to fix this error : " Module not found :can't resolve popper.js "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459917/how-to-fix-this-error-module-not-found-cant-resolve-popper-js#comment118445128_57460355)

Comment: Thank you @Ramakay. `npm i @popperjs/core` got rid of the popper problem but now when I check the webpage, after the second slide comes in, I get this error: `Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')`

Comment: Are you able to add a stackblitz or equivalent workspace to look at.

Comment: I have been able to fix the error! turns out there was a typo when I was altering the bootstrap  carousel! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Install **Bootstrap** and **React-Bootstrap** using npm, yarn, or pnpm.

```
npm i bootstrap react-bootstrap
```

**2)** Go to the `globals.css` file present inside `app` directory. At the top of file add the following code :

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

**OR**

Go to the `layout.tsx` file present inside `app` directory. At the top of file add the following code :

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

**3)** You can add the bootstrap styling to elements using `className` .

To use bootstrap components like `Container, Button, Form` etc, you can import them from **react-bootstrap** and use them like normal components.

**Eg :**

```
import { Button, Col, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <h1 className="text-danger fw-bold">Home</h1>
          <Button variant="primary" className="mt-5 ">Click Me</Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

That's it you are all set to use bootstrap in your Next.js application.