# My toggle button navbar not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on the small size toggle button it neither works nor responds.  What could be the problem here? I tried some solutions but failed.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:darkslategrey">
    <!--navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable navbar-light bg-faded">
        <!--intro navbar-->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-icon navbar-toggler-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu"><!--responsive collapse menu--></button>
        <span class="navbar-brand-icon">Bootstrap</span>
        <!--navbar logo-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
            <!--in the item-->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">About us</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--header-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-page">
        <div class="lead">
            <h1>Welcome in Helper Classes</h1>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <script src="bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors (check your console)?

Comment: Do you include jQuery and bootstrap js?

Comment: I would say pull up jQuery script to be placed before(upper) than the bootstrap.js

Comment: bootstrap js uses jquery inside it. Load jquery before bootstrap js

Comment: I am afraid some one comes next and make an answer with my comment

Answer (score 1):

As seen in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661863/bootstrap-min-js6-uncaught-error-bootstrap-dropdown-require-popper-js) you need to have a few additional script [**files**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start) loaded for bootstrap to work.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:darkslategrey">
<!--navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable navbar-light bg-faded">
    <!--intro navbar-->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-icon navbar-toggler-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu"><!--responsive collapse menu--></button>
    <span class="navbar-brand-icon">Bootstrap</span>
    <!--navbar logo-->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
        <!--in the item-->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">About us</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
<!--header-->
<div class="container">
    <div clsss="header-page">
        <div class="lead">
            <h1>Welcome in Helper Classes</h1>
        </div>
        <hr>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not good approach to load all js files in the top of the page/document, bad practice for SEO and reduce page load speed.