# Summernote won't load toolbar panel

Tags: jquery, .net, razor, bootstrap-4, summernote

Hi I'm trying to use summernote and I still cannot understand why it won't fully load, even after reshuffling all my script files and double checking if everything is in order , I got only the resizable textbox but I can't get it to work completely, This is how it looks right now: 
[image]

As you can see I cannot seem to get the panel to show up. These are script files :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="box-shadow:none">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<!-- Web Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/all.min.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/font-awesome.min.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/font-awesome.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
@Html.IncludeVersionedCss("/Content/summernote.min.css")
@Html.IncludeVersionedJs("/Scripts/summernote.min.js")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Html.IncludeVersionedCss("/Content/time.css")
@Html.IncludeVersionedCss("/Content/timeline.css")
@Html.IncludeVersionedCss("/Content//bootstrap2-toggle.min.css")
@Html.IncludeVersionedCss("/Content/jquery.timepicker.css")
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
</head>
<body style="padding-top:0px">
@RenderBody()
<footer></footer>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/interactjs@1.3.4/dist/interact.min.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/customBundle")
<script src="~/Scripts/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
@Html.IncludeVersionedJs("/Scripts/bootstrap2-toggle.min.js")     
@Html.IncludeVersionedJs("/Scripts/jquery.timepicker.min.js")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

My script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.htmleditor').summernote();
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="htmleditor">@Model.Item.GetPropertyValue(Model.Property).ToString()</div>
```

Where I'm I going wrong , please HELP!!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. If you open the devTools, you may see some Uncaughted Error mention your Bootsrap need popper.js.

There's two ways to solve it:

1. include the popper.js before you include bootstrap.js

   `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.0.4/popper.js"></script>`
2. include bootstrap bundle, instead of bootstrap.js only. The bundle contains popper.js

   ref: [other post's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55561967/12390423)